# If statement returning error in shell script?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

This is a pretty straight forward script yet I'm getting this error.
[image]

```
Enter a10
Enter b10
ifel.sh: 4: 10: not found
ifel.sh: 7: 10: not found
10 is lesser than 10
```

I have used a remote Ubuntu terminal for this.

Comment: Why did you post an image of your script (and not the script in TEXT)?

Comment: As an answer read this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bash-operators-vs-vs-vs

Comment: Conclusion, use `[ $a -gt $b ]`, in stead if `(($a -gt $b))`   Note the space after `[`, and before the `]`.

Comment: Yeah I just found that the whitespace was the deal. Thanks man